# .NET Link validator API?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Is anyone aware of any good link validation API. I am not looking for any kind of web crawler, just something to validate a full page or single links. I've been looking for one, because I am having some problems with mines that I cannot solve at the moment.

A few of the major problems are:

- Some async web requests are never ending
- Getting many false positives
- Getting 404 when it's a redirect

I'll post up my code in case.

First method is to start the validation

```
private void urlCheck( Link strUri )
{
    try
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri( strUri.URL , 
            ( strUri.URL.StartsWith( "/" ) ) ? 
                UriKind.Relative : UriKind.Absolute );

        if( !uri.IsAbsoluteUri )
            uri = new Uri( _page.HttpDomain + uri );

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( uri );
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.UserAgent = 
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/4.0)";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        request.SendChunked = true;
        request.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Referer = "http://www.google.ca/";
        // default : WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
        request.Proxy = null; 
        request.Timeout = 20000;

        //do not revalidate this
        WebPageCollection.DoNotRevalidateLinks.Add( strUri );
        request.BeginGetResponse( new AsyncCallback( getResponseCallback ) , 
            request );
        _webRequest++;
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Second method is the callback

```
private void getResponseCallback( IAsyncResult result )
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    string strUri = request.Address.ToString();

    Link href = new Link( strUri );
    href.URLKind = urlKind;
    href.URLType = UrlType.External;
    href.URLState = UrlState.Valid;

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if( response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect )
        {
             //TODO: Redirects
             href.URLState = UrlState.Redirect;   
        }
    }
    catch( WebException wex )
    {
        href.URLState = UrlState.Broken;
    }

    _page.Links.Add( href );
    _webRequestComplete++;
    request.EndGetResponse( result );
}
```

The two incremented variables are to make sure that both of the counts are equals, and in many cases they're not and I end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: You need to specify more about your problems. For the first (async never returning), that's easy to fix, have a timeout and assume after that timeout that it's invalid if it doesn't return.  For false positives, you need to identify exactly what is a false positive.  For 404s that are redirects, I don't understand how you can get that, either you get a 301/302 response, or you don't.  You need to elaborate more for a good answer.

Comment: By never returning I mean, that not event is ever raised, my delegate method will never be hit even if I have a Timeout delay on my webrequest. I believe, it should at least return me a response with a timeout code. But its not. By false positives I mean, either a page stated as broken when its redirect or a page stated as broken (404) but its actually valid. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you're setting `SendChunked`? That throws a `ProtocolViolationException` for me most of the time. Change the catch statement in your urlCheck() method to re-throw the error to see it.

**UPDATE**

Sorry to keep hammering a point but I think you're losing the error. It sounds like you're doing this on an ASPX page (you mentioned web.config) but you're using Console.Write in your catch so you're never seeing it. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx#ddueExceptionsToggle), a `ProtocolViolationException` will be thrown when:

> Method is GET or HEAD, and either ContentLength is greater than zero or SendChunked is true.

Comment: I am not getting any error thrown at that point. I wrote that a while ago, but if I remember correcly I had to add some stuff to the webconfig to make it work.

Comment: An important fact to note is that it's a multi threaded application.

Comment: I investigated more, and it really seems to be a some kind of protection on the server. It seems that for some sites I can only query the site really few times in a short period. I went up to 10 seconds delay between requests and still not getting any kind of responses after 1st or 2nd webrequest on the same server. Any ideas how to bypass?